# Is there any way to use support the Builder pattern in Rikulo?

Tags: dart, rikulo

I am interested in using the Builder pattern for declaratively creating UI with Rikulo. Is there a way to do so? Does the Dart syntax support a similar mechanism?

For example,

```
div(
  label(value:"OK")
);
```

Comment: Also see: [Configure Dart editor to Build UXL Files](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22710941/how-to-configure-dart-editor-to-build-uxl-files).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, it is possible. First, you have to define global functions for div, label and other ui objects. For example,

```
TextView textView([String text, String html])
=> html != null ? new TextView.html(html): new TextView(text);
```

It could be an excellent addon.