# How to configure Dart Editor to build ".UXL" files

Tags: dart, markup, dart-editor, rikulo

I have the demo code for the [Rikulo UXL ScrollView demo](https://github.com/rikulo/uxl/blob/master/example/scroll-view/ScrollView.uxl.dart) working with the Dart Editor.

- [UXL Overview](http://docs.rikulo.org/ui/latest/UXL/Fundamentals/UXL_Overview.html)

However, the set-up seems cumbersome to me.  For the example to build the .Dart file from the UXL file, (*apparently*) it needs to be named as: "ScrollView.uxl.xml".  Can the build process or Dart Editor be configured and set-up to do a more streamlined workflow like:

```
ScrollView.uxl --> ScrollView.dart
```

As opposed to the current rule:

```
ScrollView.uxl.xml --> ScrollView.uxl.dart
```

It seem to me the solution seems to lie in the UXL builder:

import 'package:rikulo_uxl/uc.dart';

Solutions welcome.

Comment: Please note:  [Dart Builder](https://www.dartlang.org/tools/editor/build.html)

Answer (score 0):

The readme of the package seems to contain exactly the code you are looking for:

https://github.com/rikulo/uxl

add this to your `build.dart` file (in the directory where your `pubspec.yaml` file is

```dart
import 'package:rikulo_uxl/uc.dart' show build;

void main(List<String> arguments) {
    build(arguments);
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately I thought that too.  However this instruction ONLY builds: "--.uxl.xml", to: "---.uxl.dart".  Which is the situation described in the question, that I'd prefer to eliminate.  Thanks for pointing it out though, I should have mentioned that the question was describing *status quo* (as *documented*).